# Generating density matrix of a wavefunction from common quantum chemistry software

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software

I am looking for density matrixes for a couple of closed shell and open-shell systems, and I wonder if there is a trivial way to make e.g.  Gaussian just generate an output for me. I may be wrong but most quantum chemistry software seems to generate the density matrix when checking SCF convergence, so it would make sense if there were an option to save it.

Comment: I'm sure there is a nicer way to do this, but I haven't found it yet. For Gaussian, IOp(6/8=3) will print the density matrix verbosely in the output file.